# Embedded CSS in XML not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, xml, google-chrome

I'm trying to have the content of an XML file properly displayed in a browser.

The following works fine in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="#style" type="text/css"?>
<article>
  <extras id="style">
    dummy { }
    headline { font-weight: bold }
    extras { display: none }
  </extras>
  <headline>This should be bold</headline>
</article>
```

The strange thing is that Chrome does see the CSS — if I don't put the xml-stylesheet instruction, Chrome warns me that "This XML file does not appear to have any style information..." and displays the XML as a tree (just like Firefox does) — but I don't know why it ignores it anyway.

Any clue ?

The `dummy { }` line is needed because somehow, both Firefox and IE ignores the first non comment line of the CSS part.

Comment: I guess, it's not possible for some reason to use an external css file, is it?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be self contained...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65031) in Chromium.